# Сыны или Сыновья

Tags: этимология, существительные, число

Зачем нужно второе существительное *сыновья* для постановки *сына* во множественное число?
Как это исторически сложилось? Есть ли у этого рациональное объяснение? Почему *сыновья* не имеет единственного числа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расширенный комментарий к ответу **JKlen**

Хочу обратить внимание на то, что форма "сыны" восходит не к именительному падежу дв.ч., а к винительному мн.ч. Здесь, вероятно, снова злую шутку сыграла Википедия, в которой со ссылкой на учебник В.В. Иванова "Историческая грамматика русского языка", 1983 г., говорится, что форма И.дв. вытеснила древнее множественное. Но в этом учебнике сказано совсем другое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этой же цитате видно, каким способом образовалась форма *сыновья*. Не совсем правильно говорить, что это сохранившаяся старая форма И.п. мн. (как у слов *крестьяне, горожане и т.п.*)

Comment: Откройте любую грамматику (Хабургаева, Елкину, Гамановича)  - и убедитесь, что формы именительного и винительного падежей двойственного числа **всегда** совпадали. Поэтому ваша трактовка "восходит **не** к именительному, а к винительному" ничего кроме удивления не вызывает.  Почему Иванов выбрал в качестве эталона винительный - это его проблемы. Во всяком случае и он не отрицает именительный как первичную форму.

Comment: @behemothus Речь в цитате идёт о В.мн., а не о В.дв. В учебнике это очевидно из ближайшего контекста. В ответе я об этом сказал, но вы зачем-то исказили "мою трактовку" при цитировании.

Answer (score 1):

> Зачем нужно второе существительное сыновья для постановки сына во
> множественное число?

Это не является "вторым" существительным. Это особая форма слова "сын" только для множественного числа актуальная. Поэтому ни о каком единственном числе речь не идет.
Искать "рациональное" объяснение нестандартным грамматическим формам - занияте вообще крайне неблагодарное. Исторические изменения грамматики (и языках вообще) никогда не были чем-то рациональным - за исключением, разве что, нескольких случаев возникновения некоторых пиджинов и койне, когда общее упрощение грамматики являлось средством стихийно-рацианального стремления к упрощению общения на стыках родственных наречий (английский в период норманнского (скандинавского) завоевания).

> Как это исторически сложилось?

Ряд существительных (на краткий -u основы) имел особые формы окончаний (-ове) для множественного числа - обычная для других существительных форма совпадала с формой для двойственного числа. После падения двойственного числа некоторые существительные сохранили старую форму множественного, "сыновья" - единственное из доживших до наших дней. Похожие формы типа "кумовья" обычно имею другое происхождения, не надо их смешивать.

Comment: А кумовья (кумухи, кумята, кумищи, кумачи, кумусики) как произошли?

Comment: @user190920 Кумовья - от собирательного значения. Остальное - вообще не об этом.я.. Простите, подробнее сейчас не могу чисто по техническим причинам, компьютерным.

Comment: Тогда, простите, механизм происхождения сыновей и кумовей одинаковый. см цитату "сыновья возникшую под влиянием собирательных на ия > ья". Кстати, подмеченная закономерность ия > ья и есть то самое "рациональное объяснение" для меня. Было бы странно если только одно слово сыновья было бы таким, а тут оказывается целая тенденция.

Comment: Нет. Именно что разный. Сыновья - из сынове **под влиянием** собирательного, а кумовья - исходное собирательное значение.  формы кумове  никогда не существовало, насколько я понимаю. Это другой тип  склонения, на согласный, там множественное - кумы.